# How To Get NMEA Sentence of GPRMC in my application?

Tags: android

I am developing a GPS app in that, I used location manager and able get the longitude and Latitude ... But, I need the NMEA 0183 format sentence for sending to the server.. how can I get that sentence help me if any one knows that

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3):

Hi you may get nmea sentence by adding NmeaListener, 
here is how to get

```
    LocationManager locationmanager;
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.addNmeaListener(new NmeaListener() {
                public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) {

                    Log.d(TAG,"Nmea Received :");
                    Log.d(TAG,"Timestamp is :" +timestamp+"   nmea is :"+nmea);


                }});
```

please note that you get all of nmea sentences like GPGGA..etc.,

Comment: Thanks for Your reply yar.. But its not working in my application when I add this code the application not showing any error but its force close showing.. how can i get that and print in the main... like output.append("NMEA Sentence"+nmea);

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to add android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION